# Glue/awswrangler job takes very long time when reading many multiple files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a very simple script that reads from s3 bucket with awswrangler:

```
data = pd.DataFrame()

for prefix_to_process in prefixes_to_process:
    if prefix_to_process:
        source_path = f"s3://{source_bucket_name}/{prefix_to_process}data/"
        logger.info(f"Reading {source_path}")
        read_df = wr.s3.read_csv(path=source_path, use_threads=True)
        data = data.append(read_df)
```

My bucket have following structure:

```
2023-10-15/12/data/zxc/file1.csv.gz
2023-10-15/12/data/zxc/file2.csv.gz
2023-10-15/12/data/zxc/file2.csv.gz
2023-10-15/12/data/zxy/file1.csv.gz
```

each file about 300-400 bytes long, there's about ~2500 files for each prefix. But thing is it takes about one hour to read a single prefix in glue!

When I run it locally, it takes only 1-2 minutes to read. What I am doing wrong here and what could be a reason for this?